# Reading remote Windows event logs takes a very long time

Tags: c#

I have written a C# program which connects to a remote host and reads Windows event logs.

```
System.Diagnostics.EventLog eventLog = new System.Diagnostics.EventLog();
eventLog.Log = "Application";
eventLog.MachineName = "remoteMachineName";
if (EventLog.Exists(eventLog.Log, eventLog.MachineName))
{
    foreach (EventLogEntry entry in eventLog.Entries)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(entry.Message);
    }
}
```

However, due to the extremely large number of events, when I run this code, it takes some time to fetch `eventLog.Entries`.

**Update:** Is there a way to read logs since a particular time (say, logs created since past 1 hour) instead of reading all logs?  My plan was to read all logs and later filter logs created since past 1 hour, but this is likely not a solution.

Comment: Infinite time to display any entries, or to finish?

Comment: How exactly did you come to the conclusion that it was infinite? Even time itself isn't infinite in its quantity thus far... Is it doing *anything* or are you just spin-waiting? Have you read a log with smaller numbers of entries OK with the same code?

Comment: A painfully long time to display all entries, and thus finish execution. Meanwhile, I checked with another host with smaller number of events and it turned out that the code indeed returns successfully after some time (around 5 minutes for a 5MB of events). I have updated my question now, as the code is alright.

Comment: Instead of trying to connect to the remote computer, create an [event subscription](http://blogs.technet.com/b/otto/archive/2008/07/08/quick-and-dirty-enterprise-eventing-for-windows.aspx) that will forward events from multiple computers to a central machine.

Comment: Use WMI instead with a query. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23816470/c-sharp-wmi-reading-remote-event-log

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb671200(v=vs.90).aspx#Y0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The short answer is no. The `EventLog` class offers no way to take the last `x` entries or entries past `y` date or anything to the effect. Additionally you're not allowed to receive the `EventWritten` event remotely which to me gives you one simple but far from ideal work around which would be to limit the logs size. If you're consistently pulling the log then you don't need it for archival purposes anyway, however if you limit it's time/size you'll never be reading that much data so your app will remain fast.

As some other folks suggested in comments the only other reasonable option is to build some middle layer to send `EventWritten` events over HTTP or something to a central server.

Comment: Thanks! I am trying to reverse the order of entries by reading `events.Entries.Cast<EventLogEntry>().Reverse()`. Let me see if it fits my need.